# Custom systemd service stays linked

Tags: systemd

I have a custom systemd service defined in `/lib/systemd/system/myservice.service`:

```
[Unit]
Description=My simple service daemon
After=network.target udev.service

[Service]
User=serviceuser
Type=simple
ExecStart=/var/lib/myservice/myservice
ExecStop=/var/lib/myservice/stop-myservice

[Install]
Alias=myservice.service
```

The service just runs a simple bash script that combines multiple tools to grab data from an USB device and process it.

Enabling the service seems to work:

```
$ sudo systemctl enable myservice.service 
Created symlink /etc/systemd/system/myservice.service → /lib/systemd/system/myservice.service.
```

Manually starting it works:

```
$ sudo systemctl start myservice.service 
$ sudo systemctl status myservice.service 
● myservice.service - My simple service daemon
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/myservice.service; linked; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Tue 2019-09-24 11:47:53 CEST; 6s ago
 Main PID: 1523 (myservice)
    Tasks: 13 (limit: 2200)
   Memory: 18.5M
   CGroup: /system.slice/myservice.service
           ├─1523 /bin/bash /var/lib/myservice/myservice
           [...snip...]

Sep 24 11:47:53 hostname systemd[1]: Started My simple service daemon.
```

But, the service does not start automatically after rebooting. And it only shows `linked` and not `enabled`:

```
$ sudo systemctl is-enabled myservice.service 
linked
```

I've tried `systemd-analyze verify myservice.service` but it only gives me unrelated information.

**Update #1**

After reboot the status reads:

```
$ sudo systemctl status myservice.service 
● myservice.service - My simple service daemon
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/myservice.service; linked; vendor preset:
   Active: inactive (dead)
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What does sudo systemctl status myservice.service output after a reboot?

Comment: see **update #1**

Answer (score 1):

It is convenient and common to intruduce a dependency between a service and some appropriate target (e.g. multi-user.target) to get the system to automatically start the service when the target is reached. Not sure if that solves all issues, but you should at least

- put your `myservice.service` file in `/etc/systemd/system/` and delete it from `/lib/systemd/system/` (that's a common and preferred way to do it due to various reasons)
- place dependencies in `[Install]` section, that way the service will be automatically enabled after reboot.
  (or instead of reboot run as root `systemctl daemon-reload`, then `systemctl enable myservice.service`, and `systemctl start myservice.service`)

Perhaps you can try a unit file like this to begin with and see if that works:

```
[Unit]
Description=My simple service daemon
After=network.target udev.service

[Service]
User=serviceuser
Type=simple
ExecStart=/var/lib/myservice/myservice
ExecStop=/var/lib/myservice/stop-myservice

[Install]
WantedBy=network.target
```

If it does not work, then perhaps network.target is not the best target to use. Depending on what your service is supposed to do it may or may not be a good idea to use some other target (such as multi-user.target).  Here is a [link](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/NetworkTarget/) with more info about the intricacies of using network.target to pull in services.

Comment: aha... that was the hint I was looking for... you need WantedBy=some.target for the service to be enabled

Comment: I'm just wondering why all tutorials say to place the files in `/etc/systemd/system/`? It looks like systemd just wants to place symlinks there to `/lib/systemd/system/`.

Comment: No, you do not need `WantedBy` to enable a service.  As yesno points out, you should put the service file in `/etc/systemd/system` and enable it from there.

Comment: BTW, if all else fails, you can enable it by doing the symlinking yourself: `cd /etc/systemd/system; ln -s myservice.service default.target.wants/myservice.service`, presuming the service file is in `/etc/systemd/system`.  All `enable` does anyway is the symlink, this way it is possible to enable services without running the system.

Comment: @Hurzlechen I think the way systemd is set up it searches /etc/systemd/system first, then /lib/systemd/system. This enables you to keep your stuff separate from the services, etc that come with the OS. In fact you can use it to supercede an existing service definition. Makes it much easier to figure out what you've actually been mucking about with ;).

Comment: I don't recommend to fiddle with systemd folders. The best is to let it manage systemd itself with `systemctl edit my.service` and its additional options `--full` and `--force`. With it you can do everything to create/edit a service or drop in file except deleting a service.

Comment: @Hurzelchen Does this answer solve your problem? If so then please accept it with a tick on the tick on the left side. I'm unsure if I should invest additional effort to help you.